# .LAS into a .CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv, las

How to change a .las file into a .csv file? Have been trying myself but no luck no far. I am just looking for something decently short that will save some time when I have to convert big .olas files into .csv files.

Comment: Currently doing a project using machine learning algorithms and requires a csv to run.

Comment: This does not make this a ML question; please notice that tags have only to do with the *content* of the question, not its context.

Answer (score 1):

use pdal to convert a .las file to csv and vice versa install it using pdal.io or pdal p

Comment: You should provide more information and an explanation in your answer

Comment: would you ilaberate that please. Like to someone who is doing it for the first time and has no idea what to do.